# DAX: How to use TOTALYTD measure on date-filtered visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have the following two measures:

- Number of Contracts = COUNTROWS(Contracts)
- Number of Contracts YTD = TOTALYTD([Number of Contracts];Calendar[Date])

The second measure works fine in most of my visuals, however I am having problems with a date-filtered matrix.

In the matrix I am filtering the visual by yesterday's month&day and I am showing the Number of Contracts YTD year by year (by placing Year in the matrix Rows).

When I do so, there is no difference between Number of Contracts YTD and Number of Contracts.

I tried nesting Calendar[Date] inside ALL, but it's not working (2020's data doesn't change, while earlier data disappears).
How can I handle it? Thanks

Comment: Is your calendar table separated/related to your main data, and have you marked it as a date table?

Comment: Woah, marking it as a date table solved the issue, thanks. But why?
How does the table type correlate with the formula working or not?

Comment: its alters the filter context in the background to work it out where it is in time and the dates needed, otherwise its just a plain filter on a table. I'll put more detail in the answer